# Модальное окно (переход на другую страницу)

Tags: html, css

Добрый день.

Используя модальное окно на css, для его вызова использую такую функцию:

```
<a href="#openModal" >Окно</a>
```

Но при данном вызове происходит переход на главную страницу, на которой оно и открывается.

Как сделать, чтобы перехода не было?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @Pepperok, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `preventDefault`

```
<script>
function click(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //stuff
}
</script>
```

Comment: к сожалению, я незнаком с такой функцией